# Facebook Pixel on Whitelabel

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager

I currently have my main website, but the checkout is on a whitelabel system with a new subdomain e.g. `mysite.whitelabelcheckout.com`

The white-label allows me to add the Facebook pixel within a GTM tag. My question is:

> Should I be adding my facebook pixel code/GTM code to my main website + the
>   white label or just the white label checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be preferable to have the Facebook Pixel on both sides. With a Facebook Pixel, domains aren't actually that important as they're generally domain agnostic. Ultimately a Facebook pixel can accept data from multiple sources and you don't need to implement anything additional for cross domain tracking (unlike other services like Google Analytics).

It is often standard practice to have something like a Facebook Pixel on any part of the user journey or purchase funnel, so if this involves crossing between two different domains then putting it on both is the best option. This gives you the flexibility of receiving PageView data from both sides (default event on the pixel) and would allow you to fire additional Facebook Pixel events on either side for custom conversions etc.

It sounds like this checkout system allows you to implement a full GTM container, this is useful as it means your only managing your Facebook Pixel tag in one place. Within GTM you can then build off the main Facebook Pixel with additional Facebook event tags if you wish.

By default, if you create a Facebook Pixel tag in your GTM container, this will then fire anywhere your GTM container is implemented. So that's the best option. Having everything with GTM is usually a good idea from a management point of view as you build out your GTM setup. If you find the scenario where you might want a specific tag to fire on one side but not the other, you can also achieve this with conditional triggers/exceptions.

Hope this helps!